# Optimal filling of pandas DataFrame column by matching values in another DataFrame

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

Basically I have two DataFrames and want to re-populate a column of the second by matching three row elements of the second with the first. To give an example, I have columns "Period" and "Hub" in both DataFrames. For each row in the second DataFrame, I want to take the value of Index (which is a date) and "Product"/"Hub" (which are strings) and find the row in the first DataFrame that has these same values (in the corresponding columns) and return the value of "Period" from that row. I can then populate my row in the second DataFrame with this value.

I have a working solution, but it's really slow. Perhaps this is just due to the size of the DataFrames (approx. 100k rows) but it's taking over an hour to process!

Anyway, this is my working solution - any tips on how to speed it up would be really appreciated!

```
def selectData(hub, product):
    qry = "Hub=='"+hub+"' and Product=='"+product+"'"
    return data_1.query(qry)

data_2["Period"] = data_2.apply(lambda row: selectData(row["Hub"], row["Product"]).ix[row.index, "Period"], axis=1)
```

EDIT: I should note that the first DataFrame is guaranteed to have a unique result to my query but contains a larger set of data than that required to populate `data_2`

EDIT2: I just realised this is not in fact a working solution...

Comment: pls show input data and what you expect as output. A copy-pastable soln is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your problem correctly, you want `merge` these 2 dataframe on `index(date), Product, Hub` and obtain `Period` from `data_1`

I don't have data but tested it on random `int`s. It should be very fast with 100k rows in `data_1`

```
#data_1 is the larger dictonary

n=100000
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(n,3)), 
                      index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01',periods=n, freq='1Min').date,
                      columns=['Product', 'Hub', 'Period']).drop_duplicates()
data_1.index.name='Date'

#data_2 is a random subset, w/o column Period
data_2 = data_1.ix[np.random.randint(0,len(data_1),1000), ['Product','Hub']]
```

To join on index + some columns, you can do this:

```
data_3 = data_2.reset_index().merge(data_1.reset_index(), on=['Date','Product','Hub'], how='left')
```